# Broadcom BCM4360 and Kali Linux

Tags: wifi, drivers, kali-linux, broadcom, proprietary-drivers

I can't get my WiFi to work on Kali Linux (Rolling 2017.2).

I recall that my wifi was working on earlier versions of Kali (and most of the guides I tried focused on those earlier versions) and I don't think it's a compatibility issue (drivers exist for this card and are/were working on other distro's). My Wifi card is this:

```
Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
```

So I tried to do the standard things e.g. get the headers:

```
apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,')
```

Comment: Hi. Please post the output of the following commands:   `lspci -vnn -d 14e4` ,  `dmesg | grep -i bcm4360` , `rfkill list all` and `dpkg | grep -i b43` . This should help us on figuring out your problem :)

Comment: I had to run another command isntead of your first lspci ( I presume you want to know what wifi card I run) ` root@kali:~# lspci -vnn | grep Wireless
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
 Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:0112]. dmesg | grep -i bcm4360 doesn't print out anything. ` rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
`

Comment: Ok I found the solution here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/470153/no-wireless-when-install-14-04-on-macbook-pro